# What does this line "_contacts?.length ?? 0" means in flutter/dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I was learning to use Contacts in flutter app, and while understanding and writing code, i saw this expression - `_contacts?.length ?? 0,`
I am not able to understand what does this mean, what is the use of question marks here?

Here is the full code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getContacts();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getContacts() async {
    //Make sure we already have permissions for contacts when we get to this
    //page, so we can just retrieve it
    final Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = contacts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (Text('Contacts')),
      ),
      body: _contacts != null
          //Build a list view of all contacts, displaying their avatar and
          // display name
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Contact contact = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
                return ListTile(
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 18),
                  leading: (contact.avatar != null && contact.avatar.isNotEmpty)
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                        )
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text(contact.initials()),
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                  title: Text(contact.displayName ?? ''),
                  //This can be further expanded to showing contacts detail
                  // onPressed().
                );
              },
            )
          : Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the page - [How to access contacts in flutter](https://medium.com/xenon-labs/how-to-access-contacts-in-your-flutter-app-3f0158ce1ee7)

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Answer (score 1):

It first checks the `_contacts`.
If it is not null, it checks the `_contacts.length`.
If the `_contacts.length` is not null, it sets its value, otherwise it sets zero.

Answer (score 1):

`_contacts?.length ?? 0`

first `?` means if contacts is `null`, don't try to call length and just return `null` because calling `.length` on null will throw an error. So basically you're avoiding a `null` pointer error.

the second `??` means if the `contacts` or `length` is `null` (i.e., the value before `??`), return `0`.

[The Dart Language Tour - Operators Section](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) is a good reference for Dart's operator.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if `_contacts` array is `null`, you will get `0` for `length`.